# Is there a way to temporarily disable alt+key navigation behavior?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, logitech-mouse

I'm using some software to bind a macro `alt+shift+r` to my mouse (it's a logitech G502) to speed up my work in photoshop... but the binding software doesn't allow `alt` to be used as a modification key.  There's little info on this, so my theory is that the software is eating the alt+key input as a window navigation input before it can reach it's "press a key to bind it" logic.  It is completely a software defect on logitech's part, but I doubt they're going to fix it on my behalf...

My hope is that this is a Windows API behavior I can break for the program somehow, so I can push the alt+key input past it and get it to bind anyway.

Is there anyway to temporarily break alt+key window navigation to test this?

Comment: Why not just change the key-binding in Photoshop to something Logi will accept? idk about Windows, but Photoshop on Mac will not accept alt/shift/R as a command at all - all commands must include Cmd (presumably Ctrl on Win) or an F-Key.

Comment: @tetsujin - photoshop CS6 doesn't offer that shortcut as something that can be edited, oddly.  It sets the brush's "mode" to clear

Comment: Ahh, CS6 - I haven't seen that in many years. I don't remember what it can & can't do, sorry.

Comment: I ended up not needing to do this by... getting a very old beta version of the program that sets the mouse's macros, that doesn't suffer from the input problem